# Importance of WebsiteURL under datastream in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to understand the benefit of 'Website URL' field when creating new datastream for a property in google analytics.

Image below

[image]

In here initially I put my own website, and then later i changed it to somethingrandom (not my website), but i still put the gtag generated on my webpage. and now when I visit mywebpage, Google Analytics still shows real time metrics for when I have visited the page.

So I wanted to know what exactly is the relevance/importance of the website url link? Given the data is being collected even when i put something totally random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the current docs, this is just an information box or metadata for users to understand. It can be empty as well and has no impact on the tracking / data collection or reporting.

I said ***as per the current docs*** as GA4 is evolving and this may or may not change in the future.

---

**Is there any confirmation / proof or documentation to back it up?**

Yes, If you look at the [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties.dataStreams#WebStreamData) to create a web data stream, this field can accept empty values as well.

> defaultUri
> string
> Immutable. Domain name of the web app being measured, or ***empty***. Example: "http://www.google.com", "https://www.google.com"

Comment: I think some third party aids/connectors e.g. WordPress plugins may use it?